# Python count boolean values using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have the following program:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'student':['a'] * 4 + ['b'] * 6,
                       'semester':[1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                       'passed_exam':[True, False] * 5})

print (df)
  passed_exam  semester student
0        True         1       a
1       False         1       a
2        True         2       a
3       False         2       a
4        True         1       b
5       False         1       b
6        True         2       b
7       False         2       b
8        True         2       b
9       False         2       b

table = df.groupby(["student","semester","passed_exam"])
          .size()
          .unstack(fill_value=0)
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
          .reset_index()
print (table)
  student  semester  False  True
0       a         1      1     1
1       a         2      1     1
2       b         1      1     1
3       b         2      2     2
```

Is it possible not to repeat values a and b in student column? I would like to have a in the first row and then blank in the second row..and at the end to get a dataframe as a result..
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign an empty string to the duplicated cases for the `student` column:

```
table.loc[table.student.duplicated(), "student"] = ""
table
```

[image]

Comment: Great!! Thank you!!